# Include customer group selection on registration form - Magento 2

Tags: customer, magento2.2.3, customer-group

I'm using Magento 2.2.3 and what I want to achieve is to put a dropdown selection for customer group on the registration page because some of them are resellers. Is this possible and if so, how do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is perfectly possible and the best approach here would be to create a custom module to do so. Without going in super depth, here's a summary of what you'd need to do:

1: Create the basic module structure
(see https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/)

2: Override the register form block to use a custom version of the register template. To do that you would create a view/frontend/customer_account_create.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" template="Your_Module::register.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Then copy the contents of vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml to /path/to/magento/app/code/Your/Module/view/frontend/templates/register.phtml

3: Add custom html & php to your override of the register.phtml form to show the dropdown of customer groups.

I would recommend using a ViewModel as a mechanism to get the customer group data. So for example, in the layout xml above you would do:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" template="Namespace_Module::register.phtml" >
    <arguments>
        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">Your\Module\ViewModel\CustomerGroups</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

This would then allow you to do the following in your register.phtml:

```
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
$groups = $viewModel->getCustomerGroups();
```

Your view model should use the inject the Magento\Customer\Model\Api\Data\GroupRepositoryInterface class and use that to get the customer groups and return them as an array. You can then use the array in the template to build the select & options.

Also ensure the name of the select dropdown is set to group_id as this should then feed through to the data processing correctly (havent tested this though)

Comment: I had trouble on the view model part. Couldn't get it right.